# How can I offset exposures in a gbm model in R?

Tags: r, poisson, gbm, offset

I am trying to fit a gradient boosting machine (GBM) to insurance claims. The observations have unequal exposure so I am trying to use an offset equal to the log of exposures. I tried two different ways:

1. Put an offset term in the formula. This resulted in `nan` for the train and validation deviance for every iteration.
2. Use the `offset` parameter in the `gbm` function. This parameter is listed under `gbm.more`. This results in an error message that there is an unused parameter.

I can't share my company's data but I reproduced the problem using the Insurance data table in the MASS package. See the code and output below.

```
library(MASS)
library(gbm)

data(Insurance)

# Try using offset in the formula.
fm1 = formula(Claims ~ District + Group + Age + offset(log(Holders)))

fitgbm1 = gbm(fm1, distribution = "poisson",
              data = Insurance,
              n.trees = 10,
              shrinkage = 0.1,
              verbose = TRUE)

# Try using offset in the gbm statement.
fm2 = formula(Claims ~ District + Group + Age)
offset2 = log(Insurance$Holders)

fitgbm2 = gbm(fm2, distribution = "poisson",
              data = Insurance,
              n.trees = 10,
              shrinkage = 0.1,
              offset = offset2,
              verbose = TRUE)
```

This then outputs:

```
> source('D:/Rprojects/auto_tutorial/rcode/example_gbm.R')
Iter   TrainDeviance   ValidDeviance   StepSize   Improve
     1     -347.8959             nan     0.1000    0.0904
     2     -348.2181             nan     0.1000    0.0814
     3     -348.3845             nan     0.1000    0.0616
     4     -348.5424             nan     0.1000    0.0333
     5     -348.6732             nan     0.1000    0.0850
     6     -348.7744             nan     0.1000    0.0610
     7     -348.8795             nan     0.1000    0.0633
     8     -348.9132             nan     0.1000   -0.0109
     9     -348.9200             nan     0.1000   -0.0212
    10     -349.0271             nan     0.1000    0.0267

Error in gbm(fm2, distribution = "poisson", data = Insurance, n.trees = 10,  : 
  unused argument (offset = offset2)
```

My question is what am I doing wrong? Also, is there another way? I noticed a weights parameter in the `gbm` function. Should I use that?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Questions that are solely about programming/debugging a program are [off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site and may be closed.  If you have a statistical question, please edit your post to emphasize it.  You can also browse the list of [internet statistical resources](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/793/internet-support-for-statistics-software) that we maintain for software-specific help

Comment: Why not just put `log(Holders)` on the right hand side and not restrict its coefficient anyway.

Comment: Even without the offset I get nan's for the ValidDeviance column for this example, I don't know off-hand what that column is supposed to be though.

Comment: This seems like a perfectly viable R coding question, w/ a reproducible example, to me. I think this should be on topic on [SO]. If you wait, we can try to migrate it there.

Comment: OK with me. Sorry about posting in the wrong forum. I thought this might be a theory question as well since I'm not sure whether it makes sense to offset the log of exposure vs use weights in a gbm model.

Comment: you have to use gbm object you just created and pass it to gbm.more together with the offset : `fitgbm2 = gbm.more(fitgbm1,offset = offset2)`

Comment: Andy W. Thanks for pointing out that you get NANs in that column no matter what. I guess I picked a bad example data set. I got numbers in that column on my actual data set which I can't share here if I don't use any offset or if I use exposures as weights. I will try your other suggestion to put log(exposures) in the formula without offsetting. Thanks.

Comment: I tried the solution from HubertL and had success. In addition, I found another solution on my own. The h2o package has a gbm model that accepts an offset. I will try this.

Comment: I'm new here. How do I accept the answer from HubertL?

Answer (score 2):

Your first suggestion works if you specify a training fraction less than 1. The default is 1, which means there is no validation set.

```
library(MASS)
library(gbm)

data(Insurance)

# Try using offset in the formula.
fm1 = formula(Claims ~ District + Group + Age + offset(log(Holders)))

fitgbm1 = gbm(fm1, distribution = "poisson",
              data = Insurance,
              n.trees = 10,
              shrinkage = 0.1,
              verbose = TRUE,
              train.fraction = .75)
```

results in

```
Iter   TrainDeviance   ValidDeviance   StepSize   Improve
     1     -428.8293       -105.1735     0.1000    0.0888
     2     -429.0869       -105.3063     0.1000    0.0708
     3     -429.1805       -105.3941     0.1000    0.0486
     4     -429.3414       -105.4816     0.1000    0.0933
     5     -429.4934       -105.5432     0.1000    0.0566
     6     -429.6714       -105.5188     0.1000    0.1212
     7     -429.8470       -105.5200     0.1000    0.0833
     8     -429.9655       -105.6073     0.1000    0.0482
     9     -430.1367       -105.6003     0.1000    0.0473
    10     -430.2462       -105.6100     0.1000    0.0487
```